# したら and したあとで - different or same

Tags: grammar

> 仕事終わったら飲みに行く。
>
> 仕事終わったあとで飲みに行く。
>
> 仕事あとで飲みにいく。

Is there any difference between these three sentences?

Does it work the same as in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40787/difference-between-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-and-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%82%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7)?

> 仕事終わってから飲みに行く。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
仕事終わったら飲みに行く
```

Focus on the conditional aspect of `when/if`. Being `仕事終わる` a true sentence, then B `飲みに行く`.

```
仕事終わってから飲みに行く
```

Indicates a short time span after  `仕事終わる`. The first thing that happens after A is B.

```
仕事終わったあとで飲みに行く
```

Indicates a larger time span. You finish work, but not necessarily you go drinking after it. You might stop by at home, for example.
That is why sentences like `離婚した後で`、付き合うことが難しくなってきました don't make sense if you change to `離婚してから`.

```
仕事あとで飲みにいくに
```

Is wrong. The correct way is `仕事の後で` or `仕事後に` using 後 as a suffix with the reading ご. This pattern is equivalent to `仕事終わったあとで飲みに行く`.